# Comparing prevstate and current state using react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-d3-speedometer

I have a gauge-meter whose needle color(initially gray), I need to change (into black) as the value for the meter changes. I tried to implement the `useRef()` to compare the change in value and update the color of the meter needle from gray to black.

But it does not seem to work accordingly. The always remains the one passed initially.

Here is the working snippet:

[React-speedometer](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-germain-f4jnq)

If there is any workaround to achieve this thing, then any help to implement this, please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
I think this works:

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactSpeedometer from "react-d3-speedometer";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("gray");
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0.5);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value > 0.5) {
      setColor("black");
    } else{ setColor("gray")}
   },[value]);


  const changeValue = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setValue(e.target.value);  
  };
  console.log("current value", color);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
  
        type="number"
        min={0.5}
        max={1.5}
        placeholder="enter number"
        style={{ margin: "20px 0 40px 0" }}
        onChange={e => changeValue(e)}
      />

      <ReactSpeedometer
        forceRender
        needleHeightRatio={0.9}
        needleColor={color}
        textColor={color}
        needleTransition={"easeCircleInOut"}
        maxSegmentLabels={11}
        segments={11}
        minValue={0.5}
        maxValue={1.5}
        customSegmentStops={[
          0.5,
          0.6,
          0.7,
          0.8,
          0.9,
          1.0,
          1.1,
          1.2,
          1.3,
          1.4,
          1.5
        ]}
        segmentColors={[
          "Lime",
          "LawnGreen",
          "GreenYellow",
          "DodgerBlue",
          "DeepSkyBlue",
          "SkyBlue",
          "DarkOrange",
          "Orange",
          "OrangeRed",
          "Red"
        ]}
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```